# Delegated Administrator only creating users

Tags: user, admin

Is it possible to give to a Delegated Administrator only the possibility to create Users, but not to modificate them or delete?

I think no. But would be nice to confirm it.

Answer (score 2):

Delegated Admins have also edit rights on users, so no you can't. Nobody can delete users however, only deactivate them.